# PWA project setup in server

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio

Can someone help me with PWA setup in server? I have installed pwa-studio in my ukfast server and when run "yarn watch" it generates a pwa dev server to visit but that url is not accessible. Does anyone have any idea how can I access that url in the server?

[image] [image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @DipakBhambhani yes, I did it using upward connector module